# Android navigation drawer - position the closed menu

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I am using Navigation drawer for bringing a left to right sliding menu in my app.
Is there a way to make the sidebar to be slightly opened(projecting out from left) during the closed state, as it is usually hidden in closed state.
[image]

Comment: This is a bad practice and contradicts to user expectations and UI guidelines

Answer (score 0):

You might have used the layout-gravity="start" for you drawer layout. you can give left of right margin as your requirement for your view.